# XAML syntax highlighting failing in Style tags

Tags: bug, syntax-highlighting

Syntax highlighting is failing in [some XAML examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2539910/trouble-animating-radialgradientbrush-in-wpf/). Everything in `<Style.Triggers>` is not highlighted on Stack Overflow.

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86959/syntax-highlighting-fails-due-to-unknown-xaml-tag-named-setter

Comment: Why it doesn't get highlighted on meta, is because you don't have any tags to match, or a lang-specification in the markup (this: `<!-- language: lang-xml -->`) =)

Comment: And why it doesn't highlight correctly after `<Style.Triggers>` is because that kind of element name is invalid in xml (I believe), and xml is the highlighting language of choice for xaml. No?

Comment: @Bart: What do we need example code here (without any highlighting) if we have a valid example on SO? And that little accident with the link...well...

Comment: @SulfurizedDemonbobby I fixed/enabled the highlighting

Comment: @Bart: Oh, I see...we clashed there, sorry. But I still think we don't need that bunch of code in here.

Comment: @J.Steen: That's definitely valid XML.

Comment: @BoltClock'saUnicorn Periods in element names? I was pretty it wasn't.

Comment: @BoltClock'saUnicorn Well, that duplicate makes a hell of a lot more sense. But if it's valid XML, Google should hurry up and stop sucking at parsing it. =D